# Cargar id de un objeto en un combobox

Tags: c#

En C#, yo necesito hacer un combobox que muestre la descripcion de un objeto pero que cargue además el id de dicho objeto sin mostrar al usuario dicho id.

Comment: Bienvenid@, dunia. Tu pregunta puede ser respondida revisando la documentación de Comboboxes en C# . Para poder ayudarte acá, necesitamos que nos muestres qué has intentado hasta el momento, y si tienes fallos, ayudarte a encontrar la solución. Edita tu pregunta con el código fuente de lo que tengas hecho. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

@dunia mira [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas posteriores sean mejor recibida. También puedes hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funciona el sitio.

Aquí tienes una forma sencilla de hacer lo que requieres:

```
string sql = "select id, descripcion from TUTABLA";
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion))
{
    da.Fill(dataset);
}

if (dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    tuComboBox.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
    tuComboBox.DisplayMember = "descripcion";
    tuComboBox.ValueMember = "id";
}
```

> `conexion` es tu variable o método que utilizas para enlazar con `SQL Server` de esto modo en el `ComboBox` el usuario podrá ver la `Descripción` y de forma interna lo manejas con el `Id`, Saludos.